# How to select range in Excel ListColumn's DataBodyRange from second to second last cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

I have data formatted as a table. I am trying to choose a range of cells in a certain column, regardless of the cells having data. The number of rows in the table will change, which is why I need to use a dynamic range.

I managed to select the entire data body range of the table column, in addition to a range from the second cell to the last.

I plan to apply a conditional formatting macro to the range if I can set the range.

I struggle with getting a range down until the second last cell in the table column.

```vb
Sub SelectRange()

Dim LC As ListColumn
Dim SecondCell As Long
Dim LastCell As Long
Dim SecondtoLastCell As Long

Set LC = Worksheets("On-going").ListObjects("Table4").ListColumns("Redos (no.)")
    'Choosing the table column with the header "Redos (no.)", works like a charm

With LC
    SecondCell = .DataBodyRange(2)
        'Choosing the second cell of the column, no problem
    
    SecondtoLastCell = .Range(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count)
        'Choosing the second to last cell of the column. Came by this accidentally while trying everything, I have no idea why it works.

    '~~~Insert Range.Here
    'THE PROBLEM IS CREATING A RANGE FROM SecondCell TO SecondtoLastCell
 
End With

End Sub
```

I feel I have tried every possibility, including `Range(SecondCell & SecondtoLastCell).Select` and `Range(SecondCell, Range(SecondtoLastCell)).Select`. All that usually happens is that one cell *above* the column header row ("Redos (no.)" is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [`Range.Resize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) here:

```vb
Set LC = Worksheets("On-going").ListObjects("Table4").ListColumns("Redos (no.)")

With LC.DataBodyRange
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = .Cells(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 2)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @BigBen! Such an elegant solution.

I got the range spot on with  `Set myRange = .Cells(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 2)`.

Comment: Ah yes of course you need to exclude the last row too, I'll update my answer to  `- 2`.